# I am getting an error in Django while trying to submit the details in my form, what should I do?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Basically I am filling in the details in my form in Django and clicking on submit but the error is appearing. What should I do?

My Error-

```
TypeError at /contact
Contact() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'name', 'email', 
'phone','desc', 'date'
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Contact(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=122)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=122)
email = models.CharField(max_length=122)
desc = models.TextField()
```

My contacts.html

```html
     <h1 class="text-center">
        Contact Us
    </h1>
    <form method="post" action="/contact">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group my-3">
            <label for="Name" class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="Name" class="form-control" id="Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group my-3">
            <label for="phone" class="form-label">PhoneNumber</label>
            <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your Phone Number">
          </div>
        <div class="form-group my-3">
          <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
          <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group my-4">
          <label for="desc" class="form-label">Tell us about Yourself</label>
          <input type="desc" class="form-control" name="desc" id="exampleDecription1">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
</div>
   {% endblock body %}
```

Comment: We need to take a look at the Contact model

Comment: just added it pls have a look tho not the whole code as stack overflow didn't allowed me to

Comment: I don't think you have.

Comment: Can you please share your `Contact` model?

Comment: I did please see it now

Comment: It might just be an issue with formatting on SO, but the indentation of your model is messed up. Also you missed the `date` field in your `Contact` model it appears

Comment: I added the date field but same error it's showing again.